# Como cambiar la ruta en la cual almaceno mis archivos

Tags: php, rutas, upload

Actualmente estoy guardando archivos PDF en una carpeta ubicada en la raíz de mi proyecto en PHP pero en este caso requiero cambiar esta ubicación a una carpeta que se encuentra en otro servidor el cual es diferente al que estoy ejecutando mi proyecto.

La manera en la cual estoy asignándole la ruta actual para almacenar los archivos es la siguiente:

```
if($res['pdf']) {
          $archivo = $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["name"];
          $ruta ="PDF/";

          if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $ruta . $archivo)) {
              // Hubo error, poner propiedad en falso
              $res['pdf'] = false;
          }          
      }
```

En la variable `ruta` solo almaceno la ubicación que es una carpeta que se encuentra en la raíz de mi proyecto.

A la ruta que deseo acceder en el otro servidor para almacenar los archivos es la siguiente:

```
/SRVNAME/E:/nuevacarpeta/proyecto/PDF/
```

Aclaro que en la ruta anterior tengo que acceder a una unidad diferente que es la `E:` y a esta ruta intente agregándole el nombre del servidor pero no funciono.

Intente asignando la misma ubicación a la variable `ruta` pero no se almacena el archivo.

Desconozco realmente si se pueda almacenar archivos en una ubicación diferente en la que se encuentra el proyecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de ir y venir me encontré con la solución a mi problema y es que el nombre del recurso compartido (ruta del archivo) no se verá así. Si es un servidor de Windows, es un UNC y se parecería más a esto `//SRVNAME/nuevacarpeta/proyecto/PDF/.`

Además, el usuario con el que se está ejecutando el servidor web necesitará los permisos adecuados para el directorio/recurso compartido.

Espero haber ayudado a alguien que se encontrara con el mismo problema.